# C++ capture chat from external window - ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux

I am in the beginning stage of my project. My project consist of a monitor system for chat programs. I need a push in the right direction on how to capture external windows and read some data from it if possible. If this is not possible can someone suggestion another approach to achieve something similar?

The idea is that my programs check active chat windows all on different threads. The program checks the chat sessions for "banned words" and warns the chatter of it.

Comment: More details. Much more.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is not possible; in general you can't access the contents of windows outside your own application.  However, it is difficult to tell because your description is vague; can you give more details on what you are trying to do?

Comment: You could sniff packets with tcpdump instead of reading contents of windows directly.

Comment: Were you able to get any further with this question? I need exactly same solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do desktop app, monitoring opened windows on a screen.

What I can recommend you is to checkout `xwininfo` command, example call gives you info about opened windows

```
xwininfo -root -all
```

Another interesting tool to check is [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/files/xdotool/).

What about window contents, ones you have windows coordinates, you can always try to run OCR on screencapture (made with `import` for example).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off monitoring the network traffic directly using something like [snort](http://www.snort.org/).